# How to replace text in the session storage value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I am working on Navigation path display

Dashboard > BusinessSelection > TaxPeriod > VehCategories > VehTaxable

for that I am using session storage. In navigation path I want replace some text For ex: "VehCategories" instead display "Category". But where I am doing mistake I am not able to understand.
I have written a if condition

```
if (text == "VehCategories") {
            text = "Category";
        }
```

and the text I am storing in session storage for that code is below

```
if (typeof (Storage) != "undefined") {
            if (sessionStorage.breadcrumb) {
                var breadcrumb = sessionStorage.breadcrumb;
                if (breadcrumb.indexOf(text) == -1) {
                    sessionStorage.breadcrumb = breadcrumb + " > <a href='" + pageName1 + "' id='" + filename + "'>" + text + "</a>";
                    var current = sessionStorage.getItem('breadcrumb');
                    alert(current);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('breadcrumb', current);
                }
            } else {
                sessionStorage.breadcrumb = "<a href='" + pageName1 + "'>" + text + "</a>";
            }
        }
```

everything is working fine. but only replacing string I am facing problem. After replace a string of final result showing below:

Dashboard > BusinessSelection > TaxPeriod > Ca

Please help me I am struggling lot.

Comment: Makes absolutely no sense to store HTML in Storage. Store only a stringified Array. Build your breadcrumb of `<a>`'s afterwards.

Comment: Also, what should happen if you click  on the 3rd item of 5 in the breadcrumb navigation. That also boggles my mind...

Answer (score 0):

I think preferred way would be to store it as a parsed array and then parsing it:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('breadcrumb',JSON.stringify([1,2,3]))
console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('breadcrumb')))
```

Than after manipulating the array elements you can build the html with **Array.reduce**.